# Why do I get Duplicate modifier for the field?

Tags: java

Why am I getting Duplicate modifier for the field resultsQueue?
Even when I change resultQueue name to every other name, I still get this error.
When I move resultsQueue inside the main function I do not get this error.

This is my code:

```
import java.io.File;

public class Test {

    // scouter info:
    static int scounterID = 1;
    static int scouterCapacity = 20000;
    static SynchronizedQueue<File> directoryQueue = new SynchronizedQueue<File>(scouterCapacity);
    static String rootDirectoryPath = "C:\\Users\\Uri Amiel\\Google Drive\\IDC\\SecondYear\\Semster A";
    static File root = new File(rootDirectoryPath);
    static SynchronizedQueue<String> milestonesQueue = new SynchronizedQueue<String>(scouterCapacity);
    static boolean isMilestones = true;

    // searcher info:
    static int searcherID = 2;
    static int searcherCapacity = 20000;
    static String extension = ".pdf";
    static // directooryqueue is same as scouter
    static SynchronizedQueue<File> resultsQueue = new SynchronizedQueue<File>(searcherCapacity);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // scouter run:
        Scouter scouter = new Scouter(scounterID, directoryQueue, root, milestonesQueue, isMilestones);
        scouter.run();

        // searcher run:
        Searcher searcher = new Searcher(searcherID, extension, directoryQueue, resultsQueue, milestonesQueue,
                isMilestones);
        searcher.run();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at the line above it:

```java
static // directooryqueue is same as scouter
```

You left `static` out of the comment, and there is no semicolon in code after it, so the `static` goes with next line, therefore having 2 `static` modifiers in declaration for `resultsQueue`:

```java
static static SynchronizedQueue<File> resultsQueue = new SynchronizedQueue<File>(searcherCapacity);
```